# Unable to download files from object storage container on bluemix using swift cli

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, object-storage

I had large set of files in the object storage container and I want to have  a backup of those so trying to download them.I had done all the set up required for swift cli and using that.I have all these object storage details from bluemix

```
"auth_url": "https://identity.open.softlayer.com",
 "endpoint_url": "https://objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/AUTH_",
 "password": "********",
  "projectId": "**************",
 "userId": "**********",
 "v3_auth_url":"https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3/auth/tokens"
```

But swift commands are not working when I was trying to download using above data

When i used this command I got object storage url and auth_token as response

```
swift auth --os-auth-url https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3 --auth-version 3 --os-project
-id ***** --os-user-id ****** --os-password *******
```

Then I was using objectstorage url and auth_token to  get the containers list but getting empty response

```
swift --os-auth-token ***** --os-storage-url ******* list
```

Further I used this command to download all files from container but didnt worked

```
swift download --all containername --os-auth-url https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3 --au
th-version 3 --os-project-id ****** --os-user-id ******* --os-password ******
```

Please some one with knowledge on this can help in downloading these files
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I find that using the appropriate environment variables makes the Swift CLI easier to use. Start by defining these

```
export OS_USER_ID='xxxxxxxx' #userId field in Bluemix UI
export OS_PASSWORD='xxxxxxxxx' # password field in Bluemix UI 
export OS_TENANT_ID='xxxxxxxxx' # projectId field in Bluemix data
export OS_AUTH_URL='https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3'
export OS_REGION_NAME='dallas' #region (change as needed)
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3 
export OS_AUTH_VERSION=3
```

You can then use the swift command line without a lot of --options. Listing the contents of the "fruit" container:

```
$: swift list fruit
apple
banana
orange
```

Download all objects in the "fruit" container:

```
$: swift download fruit
banana [auth 0.455s, headers 0.919s, total 0.920s, 0.000 MB/s]
apple [auth 0.444s, headers 0.932s, total 0.933s, 0.000 MB/s]
orange [auth 0.498s, headers 1.104s, total 1.104s, 0.000 MB/s]
```

The --all option can be used to download everything (all containers and objects). It is not used for a single container download.

```
    $: swift download --all
usercontainer/budgets.ods [auth 0.426s, headers 1.139s, total 1.140s, 0.033 MB/s]
usercontainer/get-pip.py [auth 0.440s, headers 1.109s, total 1.402s, 1.657 MB/s]
usercontainer/profile.jpg [auth 0.418s, headers 1.123s, total 5.240s, 0.415 MB/s]
fruit/orange [auth 0.000s, headers 0.064s, total 0.064s, 0.000 MB/s]
fruit/banana [auth 0.000s, headers 0.070s, total 0.070s, 0.000 MB/s]
fruit/apple [auth 0.000s, headers 0.077s, total 0.077s, 0.000 MB/s]
```

Comment: when i try to use export command it is giving me as not recognized

Comment: If you are on Windows, you need to use SET instead of export to set environment variables.

Comment: Yes I used set and after that I gave swift download containername but it gave me authenticationfailure

Comment: @mpcarl How to upload all files at onetime to container.It is allowing only one at a time.
I used this but didnt worked.
swift upload containername --all

Comment: You can list multiple files to upload with a single command. For example:
swift upload morefruit apple banana orange.